# Summarize data frame by multiple columns in R but don't change number of rows

Tags: r

In the following example, I got this data:

```
x = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b")
y = c("s", "s", "t", "t", "s", "s")
z = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
data = data.frame(cbind(x, y, z))
```

Then I need to sum up `z` by `x` and `y`, then put the sum as `w` like below. Note that I don't want to merge rows and the results should still have the same number of rows. How can this be achieved, please? Thank you.

```
x y z w
a s 1 3
a s 2 3
a t 3 7
a t 4 7
b s 5 5
b t 6 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b")
y = c("s", "s", "t", "t", "s", "t") # correction for last element
z = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
data = data.frame(x, y, z)

> ave(data$z,data[,c("x","y")],FUN=sum)
[1] 3 3 7 7 5 6
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I do similar for count instead of sum? I tried `FUN = n`. But it didn't work.

Comment: @LaTeXFan `length`.